# jQuery.url.attr('anchor') - ie complains if null

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following jQuery to trigger a tab from a menu item.

```
if(jQuery.url.attr('anchor')) {

            var anchor = jQuery.url.attr('anchor');

            if(anchor = '#goods') {
                var selected = jQuery( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "selected" );
                jQuery( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "selected", 1 ); 
            }
```

This works well in all browsers except that IE (big suprise) complains if no anchor is present in the url.
This code is in my footer and thusly gets loaded on every page.

What would be the syntax to ignore if no anchor is set?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It may be jQuery's implementation that triggered that complaint. (I won't know as I have never used that function before.)

But as much as I could see using `window.location.hash` would work just fine to get the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

The following test looks suspicious:

```
if(anchor = '#goods')
```

Did you mean:

```
if(anchor == '#goods')
```

Also what is `jQuery.url` in this snippet? I am not aware of the existence of such static property on the jQuery object. If this is some custom property maybe you should first check whether it is defined before accessing it:

```
if (jQuery.url) {
    var anchor = jQuery.url.attr('anchor');
    ...
}
```